# How would I remove everything from a string except keywords in Perl?

Tags: regex, string, perl, grep, string-parsing

I have a string like this:

```
component.kw1_tap/rt  (path/to/file1/kw1)  (path/to/file2/kw2)
```

I am able to remove the unwanted chars and produce a clean string like this:

```
component kw1 tap rt  path to file1 kw1  path to file2 kw2
```

now i want to remove everything but kw1 and kw2, so my final string should be:

```
kw1 kw2
```

Thank you.

EDIT: the strings can change and the position of keywords(kw) can change also.

Comment: i don't mind being rated negative, but if it is given with a reason that makes it a little real and something to learn from.

Comment: Do tell, how is the computer supposed to know what `kw1` and `kw2` are?  Are they going to always be the same, is something around them always going to be the same...?  That's the kind of info you have to include in your question in order for it to make any sense.

Comment: sorry if I created confusion here, kw1/kw2 are just keywords i am looking for. The strings can change of of course.

Comment: But what is then a solid part of your string?

Comment: this is my approach of doing it, if someone has a better one i will be glad to know about it.

Comment: Perhaps you should give some example Perl code as a setup, showing the string in a scalar variable and the keywords in an array variable.

Comment: You are being downvoted because (a) your question is very vague, and (b) you didn't show any evidence (i.e. code) of having attempted a solution yourself.  Please read the [faq] and [ask] for guidelines on how to post on SO.

Comment: I don't think it's vague at all. There's a concrete input string and a very clear output example. It's a very answerable question.

Comment: You didn't specify what distinguishes the strings you want to extract, but I'm guessing it's the last segment of the paths in parens: `my @matches = m{ \( (?:[^)]*/)? ([^/)]+) \) /xg;`

Answer (score 2):

This is a long shot, as you have given no clue about what is special about `kw1` and `kw2` that doesn't apply to the rest of the words in your string.

Perhaps this works for you?

```
use 5.12.0;

my $s = 'component.kw1_tap/rt  (path/to/file1/kw1)  (path/to/file2/kw2)';

my @keywords = $s =~ m|([^/]+?)\s*\)|g;

say for @keywords;
```

**output**

```
kw1
kw2
```

---

**EDIT**

If it is important that the string should be edited in-place, this code uses the same technique

```
use 5.12.0;

my $s = 'component.kw1_tap/rt  (path/to/file1/kw1)  (path/to/file2/kw2)';

$s = join ' ', $s =~ m|([^/]+?)\s*\)|g;

say $s;
```

**output**

```
kw1 kw2
```

Comment: It should be one line output or even better string modification...

Comment: @downvoter: please let me know the problem with my answer?

Comment: Just wondering...what about this code requires perl v5.12?

Comment: No reason to use `\s*` and no reason to use temp variable...

Comment: @stackoverflow: It's a tiny change to show the results on one line: just `say "@keywords";` will do the trick. I have edited my answer to show how to edit the string in-place. Were you the downvoter? A bit harsh don't you think?

Comment: @cHao: I use it to bundle `strict`, `warnings`, and `feature 'say'` into one `use`, at the same time documenting which platform I used to test.

Comment: @Borodin - Thank you for being my **teacher** :) No -1 from me, no +1 from me...

Comment: @stackoverflow: *please* be constructive. The `\s*` is there in case the real-world examples had whitespace there. It doesn't break the code. Temporary variables can often make the operation of the program clearer, and it was my intention here that the `my @keywords = ` line is the solution I am offering and the `say` is there just to document the correctness.

Comment: @Borodin - believe or not, I know what `\s*` is there for, but author didn't ask for that... Anyway - this question is a mess... so it was closed...